# OpenCV Manager Failed to detect Hardware in Galaxy S5

Tags: android, opencv, hardware

I don't know why OpenCV examples is not working in Galaxy S5 device. I have first installed OpenCV Manager and than try to install demos project but every time I got this error.

```
OpenCV Library package was not found! Try to install it? (Button : Yes/No)
```

When I click on Yes it open Play Store but it says

```
Item not found. (Button: Retry)
```

And when Open OpenCV Manager Application device it looks like below screen. Its not detect Hardware on my Galaxy S5 device. So how to check why its not detect? I also try to install all other library APK from OpenCV-Android-SDK/APK/ Path but still its not detected Hardware.

[image: Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900H)]

```
While Same thing I done on Nexus 7 Tablet and it shows Hardware detected with Its Name.
```

[image: LG Nexus 7]

> Please help me to how to solve this error in Samsung Galaxy S5

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I did many tries and finally I got solution. And I run OpenCV Program without OpenCV Managar Reference Library Project. I Solved it with some tricks.
What I did let me give in detail.

1) First Uninstall/delete all apps including OpenCV Manager from Eclipse
2) Than again Import required OpenCV_Lib and Projects.
3) Give reference OpenCV_Lib to Project.
4) Open Android.mk (project_path/jni/android.mk) and change below variable OFF to ON

```
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include full_path/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

5) Open MainActivity or StartupActivity and put this line.

```
static {
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    // Handle initialization error
}
}
```

6) Replace onResume with below code.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
try {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    mOpenCVCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    Uts.writeException(getApplicationContext(), e);
}
}
```

And than run your code.
I hope this will help you to run your code without OpenCV Manager app.

Comment: what is mOpenCVCallBack and Uts?

Comment: ok, mOpenCVCallBack is my BaseLoaderCallback but what is Uts? I can not resolve that in my code

Comment: It just handle the exception. You can just write e.printStackTrace(); instead of Uts.

Comment: I've got this error: **No Implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/objdetect/cascadeClassifier;.cascadeClassifier_1:(Ljava/lang/String;)J** do you have any idea how I can solve that?

Comment: I found out that **OpenCVLoader.initDebug()** can not load the library  in my case, but why? :(

Comment: Please download Latest OpenCV version and than try. Have you installed NDK and give path to your project using Right click on project and than goto C/C++ Build -> Environment -> add NDKROOT and its path

Answer (score -1):

Samsung Galaxy S5. Hardware "Not detected" Error.
When you install the files are resolved.

OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk -> apk -> OpenCV_2.4.10_Manager_2.19_armv7a-neon-android8.apk